# What is the best way to rollback() a statement execution failure in Java 8?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, java-8

I'm writing a transaction with Java 8. First, my code was like this.

```
try (Connection conn = DAOUtil.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(addSubscriptionSql)) {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //do work
    conn.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //handle error
}
```

But since I should rollback in case of transaction failure, I had to change the code like this. Note the two `try` blocks.

```
try (Connection conn = DAOUtil.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(addSubscriptionSql)) {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        //do work
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        conn.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); //handle error
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //handle error
}
```

My question is, is there a better (I mean simpler) way of doing this? Can I achieve this with a single try block?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use

```
try(Connection conn = DAOUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(addSubscriptionSql);
    AutoCloseable finish = conn::rollback) {

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //do work
    conn.commit();
}
```

This will always call `rollback()`, but after a successful completion of `commit()`, the rollback will become a no-op as it resets the state to that after the last successful completion of `commit()`…

Since `AutoCloseable` declares to throw `Exception` that will require to handle this broad exception type. It can be fixed with a custom type that might be useful in other cases as well:

```
interface SQLCloseable extends AutoCloseable {
    @Override public void close() throws SQLException;
}
```

…

```
try(Connection conn = DAOUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(addSubscriptionSql);
    SQLCloseable finish = conn::rollback) {

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //do work
    conn.commit();
}
```

Now, only the handling of the exception type `SQLException` is enforced.

If you don’t like the idea of `rollback()` being called unconditionally, the solution becomes less elegant:

```
boolean[] success = { false };
try(Connection conn = DAOUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(addSubscriptionSql);
    SQLCloseable finish = () -> { if(!success[0]) conn.rollback(); }) {

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //do work
    conn.commit();
    success[0] = true;
}
```

If you reset the auto-commit state at the end, you could use that as an indicator for the necessity of a roll-back:

```
try(Connection conn = DAOUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(addSubscriptionSql);
    SQLCloseable finish = () -> { if(!conn.getAutoCommit()) conn.rollback(); }) {

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    //do work
    conn.commit();
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

Comment: Clever! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It is a clever solution, so +1 for that, but I wonder how many people will understand this when they come across it in a codebase.

Comment: The SQLCloseable is a nice workaround.  Consider making it generic, such as `public interface TypedAutoCloseable<T extends Exception> extends AutoCloseable` so it could be used in any try-with-resources block.

Comment: @splungebob yes, but such a generic type develops its usefulness best when being part of a general-purpose library. It's a pity that it doesn't exist in `java.util.functions`.

Answer (score 7):

> Can I achieve this with a single try block?

No, because your `conn` object will not be available in the `catch` block of your try-with-resources. If you want to catch an exception while executing the `PreparedStatement` and explicitly do a `conn.rollback()` then the rollback will have to happen within the `try` of the try-with-resources that creates the `conn` object (i.e., using a second nested `try` block for the `PreparedStatement` call).