# Table is not fetched from mysql database to JTable in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, oop, jdbc, jtable

I created a DataConnector Class which connect my program to database. Then I created default constructor DataConnector(), which would be a common part for other parametrized constructor. So I used parametrized constructor databaseConnector(String sqlQuery, JTable table) to fetch a table from mysql database to my program (to class StaffLibraryTable). The problem is when I run program the database is fetched but the second time after adding sth to table a new row doesn't apear on the screen but there is a new one in database. This is my Class DatabaseConnector:

```
package LibraryFiles;


import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.sql.*;
public class DatabaseConnector {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarytest";
    String uname = "root";
    String password = "";
    Connection connection;
    Statement statement;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    TableModel tableModel;

    public DatabaseConnector(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, password);
            this.statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector()- first part");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
    public DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery) {
        this();
        try {
            this.preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            this.preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery)-first part");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (this.connection != null) {
                    this.connection.close();
                    this.statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery)- second part");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
    public DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery, TableModel tableModel) {
        this();
        try{
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            this.tableModel = tableModel;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery, TableModel      tableModel)- first part");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (this.connection != null) {
                    this.connection.close();
                    this.statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery, TableModel tableModel)- second part");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public static  TableModel generateTableModelStaffTable(){
        TableModel tableModel1 = null;
        DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector("select * from stafflist", tableModel1);
        return tableModel1;
    }


    public DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery, JTable table) {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            if (!resultSet.next()) System.out.println("result set is empty");
            tableModel = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet);
            table.setModel(tableModel);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery, JTable table) - first part");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (this.connection != null) {
                    this.connection.close();
                    this.statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery, JTable table) - second part");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    static boolean loginChecker (String providedLoggin){
        boolean wynik = true;
        try {
            DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector();
            String sqlQuery = String.format("select * from loggintable where login = '%s'", providedLoggin);
            databaseConnector.resultSet = databaseConnector.statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            if(databaseConnector.resultSet.next()) wynik = false;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error in LoginChecker");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return wynik;
    }
    static boolean logginService(String providedLoggin,String providedPassword){
        boolean isValidPassword = false;
        DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector();
        try {
            String sqlQuery = String.format("select * from loggintable where login = '%s' AND password = '%s'", providedLoggin, providedPassword);
            databaseConnector.resultSet = databaseConnector.statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            if(databaseConnector.resultSet.next()) {
                isValidPassword = true;
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Zły login lub hasło");
                isValidPassword = false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error in LoginService");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            try {
                if (databaseConnector.connection != null) {
                    databaseConnector.connection.close();
                    databaseConnector.statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("error in DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery, JTable table) - second part");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return isValidPassword;
    }

}
```

And this is a class where I create a DatabaseConnector object to update myJTable :

```
Package LibraryFiles;


import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class StaffLibraryTable {
    private JPanel mainPanel, leftBottomPanel, rightPanel, leftPanel;
    private JTable staffTable;
    private JTextField idWorkerTextField, nameTextField, surnameTextField, addressTextField, postcodeTextField, cityTextField, searchTextField, loginTextField;
    private JButton addButton, updateButton, deleteButton, clearButton;
    private JPasswordField passwordTextField;

    private JScrollPane scrolPane;
    private JComboBox statusComboBox;
    private JLabel searchLabel,loginLabel, passwordLabel;

    public StaffLibraryTable() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Staff");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(900,800);
        new DatabaseConnector("select * from stafflist", staffTable);
        frame.pack();
        TableRowSorter rowSorter = new TableRowSorter(staffTable.getModel());
        staffTable.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        searchTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = searchTextField.getText();
                if(!text.trim().equals(0)){
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(String.format(".*^%s.*$",text)));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                String text = searchTextField.getText();
                if(!text.trim().equals(0)){
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(String.format(".*^%s.*$",text)));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            }
        });
        staffTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int selectedRow = staffTable.getSelectedRow();
                TableModel tableModel = staffTable.getModel();
                nameTextField.setText((String) tableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow,1));
                surnameTextField.setText((String) tableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow,2));
                addressTextField.setText((String) tableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow,3));
                postcodeTextField.setText((String) tableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow,4));
                cityTextField.setText((String) tableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow,5));
                loginTextField.setText((String) tableModel.getValueAt(selectedRow,6));
            }
        });

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if (DatabaseConnector.loginChecker(loginTextField.getText())) {
                    if (idWorkerTextField.getText().equals(null) | idWorkerTextField.getText().equals("")){
                        String name = nameTextField.getText();
                        String surname = surnameTextField.getText();
                        String address = addressTextField.getText();
                        String postcode = postcodeTextField.getText();
                        String city = cityTextField.getText();
                        String login = loginTextField.getText();
                        String status = statusComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        String sqlQuery = String.format("insert into stafflist" +
                                "(`name`, `surname`, `address`, `postcode`, `city`,`login`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", name, surname, address, postcode,
                                city, login);
                        DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(sqlQuery);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dodano pracownika");
                        idWorkerTextField.setText("");
                        nameTextField.setText("");
                        surnameTextField.setText("");
                        addressTextField.setText("");
                        postcodeTextField.setText("");
                        cityTextField.setText("");
                        loginTextField.setText("");
                        nameTextField.requestFocus();
                        new DatabaseConnector("select * from stafflist", staffTable);
                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wciśnij przycisk Clear żę przygotować miejsce na nowy wpis");
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Podany login jest już zajęty");

                }
            }
        });
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                idWorkerTextField.setText("");
                nameTextField.setText("");
                surnameTextField.setText("");
                addressTextField.setText("");
                postcodeTextField.setText("");
                cityTextField.setText("");
                loginTextField.setText("");
                nameTextField.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        addButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
        public static void main (String[]args){
            new StaffLibraryTable();
        }
```

I expected my program to add new row to JTable directly after hitting a button "add", so I can see a change in JTable which is on the screen. I used Intelij to do this program. Any ideas to solve this? thank You in advance

Comment: That's a lot of code to go through. Consider working on isolating the code that causes the bug by creating a [mre] and then posting it here. This is not your entire program, but rather a small representative program that compiles for us, runs for us, and demonstrates the problem for us. The link will explain the details and how and why it is useful for both you and us. Best of luck.

Comment: You do `DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(sqlQuery);` and then you do `new DatabaseConnector("select * from stafflist", staffTable);` which if I'm be honest, doesn't make any sense, why do you need a new instance of `DatabaseConnector` to do both those calls.  `if (DatabaseConnector.loginChecker(loginTextField.getText())) {` seems like an anti pattern to me, an instance of `DatabaseConnector` should have been passed to your `StaffLibraryTable` class - AKA dependency injection

Comment: Your `DatabaseConnector` class is badly implemented.  First, it should be self contained.  That is, you should pass the credentials via the constructor and the `Connection` should be created or an exception thrown.  If it's created successfully, then it should be assumed to be in a valid state.  I might also consider using a shutdown hook to close it. You should not be passing in the `JTable` or `TableModel`, instead the instance of `DatabaseConnector` should be passing back an appropriate DTO (ie an object representation of the data), which the caller would then decide what to do with.

Comment: And don't consume the exceptions, re-throw them - it's the responsibility of the caller to determine what to do with the errors

Comment: I would check to see if "auto commit" is enabled or not.  Also, your current workflow will ruin your `TableSorter` once the table model is updated

Answer (score 0):

In a method actionPerformed, maybe you forget to fetch results on the database, or nothing change when the session closed.

```
public DatabaseConnector(String sqlQuery) {
        this();
        try {
            this.preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            this.preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Maybe you need a line with:

```
this.preparedStatement.commit();
```

See also:
[What is the best way to rollback() a statement execution failure in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785714/what-is-the-best-way-to-rollback-a-statement-execution-failure-in-java-8)

Comment: I exppected table to fetch in this line:

Comment: @PrzemysławPoskrobko with *what* line?